# Converting dataframe to a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a table of species combinations that overlap geographically.

```
Sp_a    Sp_b   prop_overlap
Cat     Dog    1
```

But I want to create a matrix that looks like this:

```
      Cat 
Dog    1
```

I have approximately 180000 combinations. Is there any quick way of converting this information in R?

I have tried:

```
    m <- matrix( NA, ncol = max(species_int$sp_a) , nrow = max(species_int$sp_b) ) 
m[ cbind( species_int$sp_b , species_int$sp_a ) ] <- species_int$prop_overlap
```

Thanks

Comment: You just need to use `reshape2::acast`, like `acast(species_int, Sp_a, Sp_b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, just had to rewrite it a little:

```
library(reshape2)
m <- acast(species_int, sp_a~sp_b, value.var = "prop_overlap")
```

Comment: If you want your answers to be understandable, then you should inlcude the library calls to load functions needed.

Comment: thanks, I have edited the above answer.